# Придти. Это что?

Tags: словарь

Собственно, почему ворд не подчёркивает это слово? Разве правильно не "прийти"?

Кстати, "прейти" тоже не подчёркивает. Это ещё что за слово?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Написание инфинитива *придти* встречается в Библии (Синодальный перевод) 60 раз. Поэтому такая форма имеет право на существование : в классической литературе, в библейских цитатах, в других авторских текстах.
Глагол *прейти* новоязом не является.
Толковый словарь Ушакова
**ПРЕЙТИ** 
прейду, дёшь, прош. прешёл, прешла; прешедший, сов. (к преходить) (книжн. устар). 1. что. Перейти. Те жребием постигнуты жестоким, а те прешли уже земной предел. Некрасов. 2. без доп. Исчезнуть, миновать.

Толковый словарь русского языка под редакцией Т. Ф. Ефремовой
**ПРЕЙТИ** 
прейти [прейти] сов. перех. и неперех. устар. 1) Перейти что-л., переправиться через что-л. 2) Пройти, минуть.

Answer (score 1):

"Придти" - "альтернативный" способ решения "коллизии" "-ии-", возникающей в "точке контакта" приставки "при-" и корня "и(д)". "Прижился" в слове "приду". В неопределённой форме **сейчас** считается недопустимым. Ранее использовался.
"Прейти" - "особенность" Ворда. "Новояз", образованный от приставки "пре-" и корня "и(д)". В "менее умных" системах - подчёркивается.